# Потоки в Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
app.get('/stream', function(req, res) {
  var stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + 'text.txt')
  stream.pipe(res)
})
```

Через потоки мы частично (по кусочкам) передаём данные в res, но как эти данные отображаются в браузере постепенно?
Ведь обычно res принимает данные (целиком как есть) и они отображаются в браузере (целиком).

Или например пример с картинкой:

```js
app.get('/image', function(req, res) {
  var stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + 'image.png')
  stream.pipe(res)
})
```

Как она подкружается кусочками?

Или .js код, например, если подгрузится только одна часть кода, а вторая часть он которой зависит первая, ещё не прогрузилась и при выполнении этого .js в браузере будет ошибка.

Answer (score 2):

Вы правильно говорите что `stream` передает данные по частям. Эти части называются **chunks**. Как правило `stream` используются для больших объемов данных (аудио/видео иногда картинки), рендеринг которых является нативным в движках современных браузеров.

Пример стриминга видео, но то же самое работает с `<audio />` и `<img />`:

*server side*

```
app.get('/video', function(req, res) {
  const path = 'assets/sample.mp4'
  const stat = fs.statSync(path)
  const fileSize = stat.size
  const range = req.headers.range
  if (range) {
    const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-")
    const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10)
    const end = parts[1] 
      ? parseInt(parts[1], 10)
      : fileSize-1
    const chunksize = (end-start)+1
    const file = fs.createReadStream(path, {start, end})
    const head = {
      'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
      'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
      'Content-Length': chunksize,
      'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
    }
    res.writeHead(206, head);
    file.pipe(res);
  } else {
    const head = {
      'Content-Length': fileSize,
      'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
    }
    res.writeHead(200, head)
    fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res)
  }
});
```

*client side*

```
<video id="videoPlayer" controls>
  <source src="http://localhost:3000/video" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

[источник](https://medium.com/@daspinola/video-stream-with-node-js-and-html5-320b3191a6b6)

По поводу .js файлов ― `stream` не передает Ваш файл в виде текста, поэтому "подгрузится только одна часть кода" это невозможный сценарий. Вы либо загрузите файл, либо он будет испорчен и попросту не откроется.

[Хорошая статья](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93), можете ознакомится чтобы вникнуть в вопрос.